# Im getting funny % signs back how do I get rid of them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, urlencode, urldecode

Im trying to parse a response from an authentication server that is url encoded. However when I do it I am getting \r\n characters. And I need to not have these in my text as I need to be able to run a regular expression that looks for white space but doesnt work with these escape characters.

So basically the string returned is:

```
ClientIP=192.168.20.31%0d%0aUrl%3d%2fflash%2f56553550_hi%3funiqueReference%3d27809666.mp4
```

After url decoding it it is:

```
192.168.20.31\r\nUrl=/flash/56553550_hi?uniqueReference=27809666.mp4
```

So you see I dont want it to have \r \n etc I want to have:

```
"192.168.20.31 Url=/flash/56553550_hi?uniqueReference=27809666.mp4"
```

As a verbatim string in c#.

Is this possible? Or do I have to do a string.replace on \r and replace with " "?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either replace `%0d%0a` with `%20` before URL decoding the string, or the `\r\n` with  after.

Since the data exists in the original string, you can't just make it go away without replacing it.

Comment: isnt there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: @Pete2k - not really. You could use RegEx to do the same, but that's even more complicated.

Comment: sorry Oded why would the auth server be using %0d%0a and not %20 in the first place. I appreciate your response :-)

Comment: @Pete2k - How would I know that? You need to ask the people behind the auth server...

Comment: Well okay this is wierd because when I look at the value in the trace.axd that asp.net it comes out how I want it, so obviously %0d%0a equates to something doesnt it? Just like %20 equates to a space?

Comment: @Pete2k - `%0d` is `\r` and `%0a` is `\n`. This is the URL encoding for each.